# How to change highcharts bars width individually

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to plot a bar graph using HighCharts. So far so good, but I want to have the bars with different widths based on the category.

I have 2 categories, "Cat A" and "Cat B". The normal behavior is for them to be plotted identically, but I want Cat B to be thinner than Cat A.

I've been going through the documentation and tried with [lineWidth](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--lineWidth), but it only seems to work with line graphs.
Maybe this can be done programmatically? I played around with the object in Chrome's console but haven't found a useful property/method..

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Hartimer/jWxTm/3/) is what I have so far.
Any help/tips/links would be much appreciated! And thank you in advance

P.S.: I would also like to get ride of the first grid line on the left, next to the x-values labels... I've done it, can't remember how

Comment: To solve de P.S. use xAxis: {lineWidth: 0,tickWidth: 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. LineWidth does the trick. Based on [this](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17023&p=70650&hilit=different%20widths) post you can specify specific widths for each series. Combined with a little aritmetic you can easily produce different widths bar charts.

I updated my example, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hartimer/jWxTm/8/). It feels a bit "hacky" but for my use case is enough.